# What does it mean when substituted equations cancel?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Suppose we have some system of equations of the following form, where $x, y$ are variables and $t_i$ are parameters, and $k, l$ are coefficients (all values are in $\mathbb{R}$).

\begin{align}
k_1x + l_1y + t_1 + t_2 &= 0 \\
k_2x + l_2y + t_2 + t_3 &= 0 \\
k_3x + l_3y + t_3 + t_4 &= 0 \\
\vdots\\
k_nx + l_ny + t_{n} + t_1 &= 0.
\end{align}

Then by "sequentially" substituting using the $t_i$ parameters, we obtain some equation that will look like
$$
x \sum_{i=1}^n\pm k_i + y \sum_{i=1}^n\pm l_i = 0
$$
if $t_1$ cancels with itself in the substitution.  But now suppose the sums of the coefficients themselves each equal zero, i.e.
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\pm k_i = \sum_{i=1}^n\pm l_i = 0.
$$
Geometrically what is going on in such a situtation?  If this happens, am I correct in assuming that any pair $(x, y)$ must satisfy the original system, and so all the original equations are linearly dependent in some way?  If the sums did not cancel to zero, then the set of solutions to such an equation would be a line or a point, but if they do I am guessing this means that all the equations form hyperplanes that coincide?

The answer is not obvious to me, for consider the following example:
\begin{align}
\frac{3}{2}-2x-3y-t_1 &= 0\\
1 - x + y- t_1 - t_2 &= 0\\
\frac{1}{2}-x-4y+t_2 &= 0.
\end{align}
In this case, substituting the $t_i$ for one another leads to cancelation of all terms, i.e. after doing the sequence of cancelations we get $0=0$.  But geometrically these equations seem to be defining different objects, so it is unclear to me why they canceled out?  Can someone expain what is going on here?